# ReactJS breaks code after being imported on Symfony project

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, symfony, webpack

I am trying to integrate ReactJS on my Symfony 5 project but just after importing it, it seems to break the code.

I have followed the mentioned steps on [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/reactjs.html) and [Symfony Casts series](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/reactjs):

1. Install Webpack Encore on the Symfony project.
2. Install dev dependencies `react` and `react-dom`.
3. Create a file like `app_react.js` in `assets/js/` and then add it as a new entry to `webpack.config.js` with `.addEntry('app_react', './assets/js/app_react.js')`.
4. Reference `app_react.js` in `base.html.twig` with `<script src="{{ asset('build/app_react.js') }}"></script>`
5. Enable React presets on Webpack Config: `.enableReactPreset()`
6. Create an HTML element into (i.e.) `templates/user/base.html.twig`: `<div id="app-react"></div>`
7. Compile assets with `yarn encore dev --watch` (everything compiles).
8. Import `React` in `app_react.js`

After this point, if I only debug a simple `console.log('Hello world')` is printed, but If I import `React` no code is executed after. I already tried the usual way to print some code with React:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

console.log('This is not being printed');

const SomeText = () => (
    <h2>Some Text</h2>
);

ReactDOM.render(<SomeText />, document.getElementById('react-app'));
```

This is what the browser source shows `app_react.js` file:

[image]

And just in case, this is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .copyFiles({
        from: './assets/image'
    })
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('app_react', './assets/js/app_react.js') // Step 3
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })
    .enableSassLoader()
    .enableReactPreset() // Step 5
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue might be in step 4. Instead of using

```
<script src="{{ asset('build/app_react.js') }}"></script>
```

should probably be:

```
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app_react') }}
```

Webpack encore will look up the `manifest.json` to figure out which file(s) to include. Likely there is more than just the `app_react.js` file.

Comment: yep, that worked. I guess the Symfony Casts video is maybe old. I thought it but I didn't code it. Thank you